# Paypal Plus pay by upon invoice JavaScript SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I want to offer pay upon invoice in the checkout.
But is is not displayed. The other possibilities like paypal, credit card are displayed.
My script looks like this:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?php echo PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID; ?>&currency=EUR&locale=<?php echo $paypalLocale; ?>">
```

I have also tried to add marks:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&components=buttons,marks"></script>
```

But it the pay upon invoice is not shown.
Currently I am trying it in the sandbox.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

That is not PayPal Plus. That is the regular PayPal Checkout SDK.

To integrate PayPal Plus for Germany and Pay Upon Invoice, see [the relevant documentation.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/de/)  PayPal Upon Invoice may require applying for the feature for use in live.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see. Can I use the JavaScript SDK for Paypal plus?

Comment: Not that one, no. It's a separate PayPal Plus SDK

Comment: Where can I find it? I thought it is the one I am using.

Comment: Integrate a Payment wall, in the documentation. If it doesn't load that's a problem with the site

Comment: The website with the payment wall https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/de/integrate/integrate-payment-wall/ gives a 404. I am not sure if I should create a button with an AJAX call for the curl Paypal plus URL or use an iframe.

Comment: I am now using the REST API. So far I get the access token, create the payment and got back an approval_url. But when I open the URL 'pay upon invoice' is not shown. What do I have to do that it is shown?

The approval_url looks like this:
```https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-123...```
May be the "express-checkou" is wrong?

Comment: You need to integrate the payment wall, there is no other way.

Comment: I want to. I can see the payment selection. Unfortunately the paypal website is not working. I did this:
`
echo '<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript">
                </script>';
        echo '<div id="ppplus"></div>';
        echo '<script type="application/javascript">
        var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "' . $approval_url . '",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "sandbox",
        "country": "DE"
        });
        </script>';
`

Comment: That looks right for the inline payment wall. Use https://www.paypal.com/de/webapps/mpp/pui-start to apply for Pay Upon Invoice in live and contact PayPal if you need support

Comment: Clicking the link said 'payment upon invoice is currently not available'. So, I can not even test it in sandbox?
With this link I can log into the paypal page: "https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js"

But with this link "https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js" I got an error:
Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/3d7/75d996b1ea8aca598821313165911' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri 'self' https://*.paypal.com".

Which is right?

Comment: If it says it's not available, it's not available. Contact PayPal for support if you like, and they will likely simply repeat that it is not available.

Comment: I have spoken with paypal. They don't want to help me because I am having a developer account.

Comment: I read in the paypal community forum that "purchase on account" has been stoped.